# How to set the starting scores of value related scores to 100 in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalize

This is such a simple question but I can't find it using the terms 'normalize' or the overused term 'index'. How do I set the start value of all my 'cars' to 100? In reality there are 52 cars and much more timestamps.

```
import pandas as pd

ExampleOfWhatIHave = {'Car':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                      'Hour':['1', '1', '2', '2'],
                      'Car-speed':[10, 20, 11, 19]}

ExampleOfWhatINeed = {'Car':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                      'Hour':['1', '1', '2', '2'],
                      'Car51-speed':[100, 100, 110, 95]}
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(ExampleOfWhatIHave)
df = pd.DataFrame(ExampleOfWhatINeed)
```

Comment: what condition should it fullfill? - why there is 110 and 95?

Comment: The Index number is standard 100, as a ratio to a base number, so that the relative growth/decrease is a percentage of that 100, hence 11/10*100 becomes 110 and 19/20*100 becomes 95. Let me know if you are still in the dark, but also see the nice solution below :-).

Comment: in this case to A and B correspond to 10 and 20 then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this nice one liner?

```
df['Car51-speed'] = 100 * df['Car-speed'] / df.groupby('Car')['Car-speed'].transform('first')
```

Comment: That is very sexy. Because I am less of a genius, and cant do things like df['Car51-speed'] = 100 * df['Car-speed'] / df.groupby('Car')['Car-speed']#.transform('first') to find out what happens here, feel free to add an explanation for the magic for us mortals

Comment: @Charles I have posted an explanation bellow

Answer (score 1):

This is an explanation of Quixotic22's answer as it was easier than writing it in a comment

Starting with the Denominator

df.groupby('Car') group the dataframe by the values on the car column, the .transform('first') then selects the first value for each group so
`df_1.groupby('Car').transform('first')`

gives:

```
  Hour  Car-speed  Car51-speed
0    1         10        100.0
1    1         20        100.0
2    1         10        100.0
3    1         20        100.0
```

the addition of ['Car-speed'] selects just that column as a pandas series

`df_1.groupby('Car')['Car-speed'].transform('first')` thus gives:

```
0    10
1    20
2    10
3    20
Name: Car-speed, dtype: int64
```

On the Numerator we have `100 * df_1['Car-speed']`

this is simply the 'Car-speed' column as a series multiplied by the value 100 giving:

```
0    1000
1    2000
2    1100
3    1900
Name: Car-speed, dtype: int64
```

We divide these Series giving a Series where each value is the result of the division of the values at that index

```
0    100.0
1    100.0
2    110.0
3     95.0
Name: Car-speed, dtype: float64
```

this resulting series is set to the column 'Car51-speed' of the data frame creating a new column

Output:

```
  Car Hour  Car-speed  Car51-speed
0   A    1         10        100.0
1   B    1         20        100.0
2   A    2         11        110.0
3   B    2         19         95.0
```